# Fortran 95, How to read blank (letter space) character from the end of the line?

Tags: arrays, fortran, character, fortran90, intel-fortran

I try to modify my program to read lines that contain blank charaters (written with space) at the end of the line. I'm using Intel compiler (Fortran 95).

In the program i'm using the command line:

```
character*(*) line  !this is the character line to where we read

...

...

read (unit=11, '(A80)') line
```

So in the file (*.txt-file), the line is:

```
R=
```

The last character of that line is blank character (space).

Is there any way to find out that line is 3 characters long and the last character is blank?

Thanks!

Is there any way to find out that line is 3 characters long and the last character is blank?

I just get character-array : 'R=' with many blank characters in the end.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in Fortran 95 (and you've tagged the question [tag:fortran90]). It's really very difficult to do this in F95, but very easy in current Fortran. 1995 was almost 30 years ago.

Comment: The strings in Fortran 95 and earlier are fixed width and blank-padded. That's how they work. For strings with adjustable length use Fortran 2003 and later.

Comment: In Fortran 95 you could read the file as an direct-access file of one-byte records, but that would be a very unfortunate way to do it and would only work with compilers that actually allow single byte records.

Comment: So Fortran 2003 has, perhaps, somekind of length function that can provide an answer to this question? I'll search for that..

Comment: Mikko also asked this in the Intel forum, where I answered. I have no idea why Fortran 95 is specified, since the Intel compiler is Fortran 2018.

Comment: I don't know if it is the case here but there seems to be a confusion in some between the source form and the standard - anything fixed form is thought to be "Fortran77", anything free form is a later standard, usually either Fortran90 or Fortran95. Mikko, is this the case here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just about use the `size=` specifier in a read statement, but it's horribly contrived.

The following code allocates (and then reallocates) an allocatable character called line.

```
program test
   implicit none
   character(len=:), allocatable :: line
   integer :: un = 10

   open( un, file="test.dat" )
   line = read_one_line( un );   print *, "["//line//"]", len( line )
   line = read_one_line( un );   print *, "["//line//"]", len( line )
   close( un )

contains
   function read_one_line( u )
      character(len=:), allocatable :: read_one_line
      integer, intent(in) :: u
      character(len=1000) buffer
      integer chars_read

      read( u, "(a)", advance="no", eor=100, size=chars_read ) buffer
 100  read_one_line = buffer(1:chars_read)
   end function read_one_line
end program test
```

For a data file test.dat containing lines

```
one 
two
```

(with the requisite numbers of blanks at the end of each line) it produces, with the square braces [ and ] just to indicate the size of line,

```
 [one ]           4
 [two  ]           5
```

Comment: Was it available in Fortran 95? I honestly do not know these details. The example could probably be changed to demonstrate that it does not actually strictly depend on the deferred-length characters used there.

Comment: I think deferred-length characters came in with Fortran 2003, but I'm not sure if @Mikko T is really stuck with Fortran 95.

Comment: Yes, deferred length and allocate on assignment are F2003, and I'm not sure when the size specifier on read came in. But like you I don't believe that Mikko is restricted to the archaic Fortran95